# pyBrain using letters as input

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, pybrain

With pybrain, it's not possible to use letters as input in a dataset. For example, if I do this:

```
from pybrain.datasets import ClassificationDataSet
ds = ClassificationDataSet(2)
ds.addSample(('a','b'),1)
```

I get:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: a
```

Does it make sense to convert each letter to an integer and make those integers be the features for pybrain? For example, the letter a would be 1 and the letter z would be 26.

My concern with this is that there is 0 relation between letters, and I'm not sure whether a number replacing each position in the string would be incorrectly treated as greater/less quantities of some feature by the neural network.

Comment: You need a [one-hot-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot), or [word embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_embedding)

Comment: Thanks - used one hot encoding and got better results.